# Is there a correct way to add custom Javascript to an ASP.NET MVC 5 page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

At the moment, I have added the jQuery source file to my ASP.NET project's Scripts folder. In the _Layout.cshtml page, I have included ~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js. Right now, I can include jQuery code on every page I make this way:

```
If this page shows a popup I was succesfull.

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("works!");
});
</script>
```

However, I don't want to include a full script in every view. I would prefer to create a seperate JS file, put it in my Scripts folder, and then include it using Razor.

```
@{ 
    //Razor Magic inserting Javascript method!
 }

If this page shows a popup I was succesfull.
```

How do I do this? And is it the "correct" way to include a unique Javascript file for a single page?

Comment: Just include `<script src="~/Scripts/YourScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in the page.

Comment: If you want to debug your JS code easily, it needs to been in a separate js file anyway (the debugger only lets you breakpoint *either* mvc code *or* JS code in views). You can breakpoint JS in the dynamic content that appears at the top of the solution at run-time, but that is tedious. Also bundling is the best way to go (as said below) as it makes best use of browser caching and auto-minification of your JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best and elegent way to solve your problem in MVC is making `Bundles` Known as `Bundling and Minification`.

See more here  :- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I now need to figure out how to make that work in MVC5 though. Apparently, I need to use nuget to include this functionality.

Comment: @Bas...welcome..bundling is same for mvc4 and mvc5 there is no difference at all and visit this useful link also    http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/c72b040113-Asp.net-MVC-4-performance-optimization-with-bundling-and-minification.html

Answer (score 22):

You can put your page specific JS code in a separate JS file and can refer to your specific Views using the following piece of Code:

1) You need to put this section in your **_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js)">
    @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
</head>
```

2) You need to add @section to the View in which you want to refer your JS file - (_ABCDView.cshtml)

```
@section JavaScript
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SampleScript2.js")"></script>

}
```

**NOTE:** 
@RenderSection, false, means that the section is not required on a view that uses this master page, and the view engine will ignore the fact that there is no "JavaScript" section defined in your view. If true, the view won't render and an error will be thrown unless the "JavaScript" section has been defined.

And you are good to go!

Hope this will help you.

Thanks, 
Swati