# Add custom js file to cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net core. I would like to add My custom `js` file to `document.ready`. How can I add this?

My Code =>

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("../MyFolder/CareerHelper.js")"></script>  
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This is error show =>

```
http://localhost:8089/MyFolder/CareerHelper.js  404 Not Found
```

I also tried this way => [Is there a correct way to add custom Javascript to an ASP.NET MVC 5 page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720250/is-there-a-correct-way-to-add-custom-javascript-to-an-asp-net-mvc-5-page)

but it's not working.

Careerhelper.js:

```js
importScripts('./ApiHelper.js');  

import * as apihelper  from './ApiHelper';

function getIndustry() {   

    $.ajax({
        url: `${apihelper._api}/jobindustry`,
        type: 'GET',        
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Where is your `CareerHelper.js` file? in `wwwroot` ?

Comment: @FarhadZamani, No.Its not inside in wwwroot

Comment: Where is you file then?MyFolder shold be in wwwroot

Comment: Show the complete path of `CareerHelper.js`

Comment: @JawwadAhmed, Main reason is I have a lot of ajax call and I would like to extract this part and write in other js file then I will call this ajax.So Later I can reuse this ajax call but Now I cant do this way.

Comment: @FarhadZamani, Pls check the update.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET Core), or are you using ASP.NET 5 MVC(.NET Framework)? The tag suggests core, your code and linked resources suggest framework.

Comment: Hi @ShweSinNyein, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to take some extra steps with IIS, check below link. if that helps

https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

If your `MyFolder/CareerHelper.js` etc static files are outside of [the `wwwroot` folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows#web-root), to serve these files and make it work as expected, you can try:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "MyFolder")),
        RequestPath = "/MyFolder"
    });

    //...
```

*Add reference to your js file*

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/MyFolder/CareerHelper.js"></script>
}
```

*Folder structure*

[image]

Test Result

[image]